# Failed to parse data from SAP table via Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, gigya

I am trying to extract data from SAP using **SAP CDC** Connector in ADF. The source data looks something like this.

> START_DT|PROD_NAME|END_DT
> 20201230165830.0|BBEESABX|20180710143703.0

When we perform a preview data on the source, we are getting data just like above. But while performing copy via copy activity, below failure is observed :-

> Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SapParsingDataFailure,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed when parsing data, parsing value: 'ESABX 201807', expected data type 'Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.ClrTypeCode'.Please check your origin data in SAP side,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SapRfcHelper,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=Input string was not in a correct format.,Source=mscorlib,'

I have tried several combination and changes on sink side such as changing parquet to csv, changing Copy behavior to all available options...but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have hiding fields in the SAP Extractor? (RSA6). Try this workaround, make a selection of all fields in the SAP CDC connector and run it again.

Comment: yea I already tried this and it worked..but not able to find the root cause as I dont have much knowledge about SAP systems...any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error to this recently where I was using a Dataflow with a SAP CDC connector for the Source and Parquet file as the sink. It was a pretty basic workflow with two activities. After some digging and not getting any real answers from searching the internet, i changed my data flow from a Parquet Sink to a Delimited Text File sink and that solved the issue.